# Plotting point data from one dataset on polygon

Tags: qgis, point, spatial-join

I have a point dataset with information on: date, number of beneficiaries, and type of assistance.

I want to plot/map this info on a country polygon. I tried joining attributes by location, but that didn't work for the text fields.

Any ideas on how to map the point data on the polygon?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Could you be more specific, e.g. provide an example you want to recreate, about what you mean by "plotting data"/"map the point data". Also, please describe what further processing you intend.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. Let's assume I want to visualize the data found in this point shapefile (https://data.humdata.org/dataset/iraq-affected-persons-locations-0-0) on this country polygon (https://data.humdata.org/dataset/iraq-admin-level-1-boundaries). I would like to visualize, via a heatmap/categorizing the point data (the What_assis column which is text) and then also a similar heatmap for IDPs_in_Ca. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you had a look at the symbology options for point data?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Eric. Yes, I have but I would prefer to categorize the polygon instead of the points if that makes sense? I would prefer to color the polygon instead of having two layers, the country polygon and then the points categorized on top of that.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense, because heatmaps are based on point data. Also, this is what makes GIS powerful, the ability to display several datasets without having to merge them.